# Where are Python dist-packages stored in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, python, directory-structure, django

I am trying to find this path on FreeBSD but it is not working: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

This same path is working on Ubuntu.

Can please some tell me where I can find Python dist-packages? Actually, I am trying to find the Django folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your `python` and then type

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

You are likely to have something ending in `site-packages` or `dist-packages` in there.

Django probably has its own, additional, folder structure (I know that web2py does), so you might have more luck using a web page with that code and analysing the output from that.